# Removing odd \n, \t, \r and space combinations from a given string in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, replace, split

I have a long string which contains various combinations of \n, \r, \t and spaces in-between words and other characters.

- I'd like to reduce all multiple spaces to a single space.
- I want to reduce all \n, \r, \t combos to a single new-line character.
- I want to reduce all \n, \r, \t and space combinations to a single new-line character as well.

I've tried `''.join(str.split())` in various ways to no success.

- What is the correct Pythonic way here?
- Would the solution be different for Python 3.x?

Ex. string:

```
ex_str = u'Word   \n \t \r   \n\n\n word2    word3   \r\r\r\r\nword4\n    word5'
```

Desired output [new new-line = \n]:

```
new_str = u'Word\nword2 word3\nword4\nword5'
```

Comment: Don't name a variable `str`; it masks the built-in type.

Comment: _"I want to reduce all \n, \r, \t and space combinations to a single new-line character as well."_ Do two spaces in a row count as a "\n, \r, \t and space combination"? If so, how do you decide when to use this rule, and when to use the first rule?

Comment: @Kevin, in-between words, I have anything from a single \n, single \t, single \r, single space to any (or same) of 1, 2, 3 or all 4 of them. If any combination has one or more new lines, I want it to be a single new line. If it has only spaces (one or more), I want it to be a single space.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I replaced the example string name. Thank you.

Comment: You need to clarify your inclusion of `\t` in the newline rules there. Should `word1\t\tword2` result in `word1 word2` or `word1\nword2`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, it already is included. word1\t\tword2 should be word1\nword2. If it was word1\t   \tword2, it would also be word1\nword2. It's my third point on the question's requirements. Please see: >> 'reduce all \n, \r, \t and space combinations to a single new-line character'.

Comment: @Phil: Yes, that is what I am referring to. Since `\t` is a *tab* character and not commonly used as a line separator, the inclusion doesn't make sense. I want you to confirm it should be used as a line separator *anyway*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I'm sorry I got confused there. Your solution is the correct one for the above case scenario. If you wanted to exclude the \t out of all this and keep tabs as they are (no matter how many), how would that be? Would you mind adding that to your solution as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a combination `str.splitlines()` and splitting on all whitespace with `str.split()`:

```
'\n'.join([' '.join(line.split()) for line in ex_str.splitlines() if line.strip()])
```

This treats each line separately, removes empty lines, and then collapses all whitespace *per line* into single spaces.

Provided the input is a Python 3 string, the same solution works across both Python versions.

Demo:

```
>>> ex_str = u'Word   \n \t \r   \n\n\n word2    word3   \r\r\r\r\nword4\n    word5'
>>> '\n'.join([' '.join(line.split()) for line in ex_str.splitlines() if line.strip(' ')])
u'Word\nword2 word3\nword4\nword5'
```

To preserve tabs, you'd need to strip and split on *just* spaces and filter out empty strings:

```
'\n'.join([' '.join([s for s in line.split(' ') if s]) for line in ex_str.splitlines() if line.strip()])
```

Demo:

```
>>> '\n'.join([' '.join([s for s in line.split(' ') if s]) for line in ex_str.splitlines() if line.strip(' ')])
u'Word\n\t\nword2 word3\nword4\nword5'
```

Comment: This may not satisfy need 3 if it is `\t\t `. It should be replace by a newline. @Martijn Pieters

Comment: @zhangyangyu: I am not 100% convinced that that is the case.

Comment: I think simple `\t`s shall be converted to newlines as well.  The example string does not have that case, however.

Comment: @Alfe: See the comments on the question; the OP was confused about those.

Comment: I saw the comments.  I don't see confusion about the question whether tabs shall be translated to newlines, at least not after the clarification »word1\t\tword2 should be word1\nword2«.  But anyway, he asked about a new feature of ignoring the tabs later, so you maybe he reconsidered that ;-)

Comment: @Alfe: Specifically [this reply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809119/removing-odd-n-t-r-and-space-combinations-from-a-given-string-in-python/17809153?noredirect=1#comment25985797_17809119) to my comment expressing incredulity that the OP really wanted to treat tabs as line separators.

Comment: That's what I meant.  I read it as an expression of having new thoughts about whether those awkward tabs couldn't be handled differently than just converting them to newlines.  Anyway, if in any case the OP finally decided to convert tabs to newlines (as he originally stated), then your solution would not be fit to that task because `splitlines()` does not split at tabs.  Just wanted to mention that.  No hard feelings.  Actually I prefer more abstract solutions over unreadable regexp wastelands.

Comment: @Alfe: No offense taken; I am fully aware that `.splitlines()` does not split on tab characters, which is *why* I pressed the OP on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

Use simple regexps:

```
import re
new_str = re.sub(r'[^\S\n]+', ' ', re.sub(r'\s*[\n\t\r]\s*', '\n', ex_str))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex:

```
>>> s
u'Word   \n \t \r   \n\n\n word2    word3   \r\r\r\r\nword4\t    word5'
>>> re.sub(r'[\n\r\t ]{2,}| {2,}', lambda x: '\n' if x.group().strip(' ') else ' ', s)
u'Word\nword2 word3\nword4\nword5'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using regex which replaces tabs with a space `u'word1\t\tword2'`, or do you really want to add a line break here too?

```
import re
new_str = re.sub(r"[\n\ ]{2,}", "\n", re.sub(r"[\t\r\ ]+", " ", ex_str))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
'\n'.join(str.split())
```

Output:

```
u'Word\nword2\nword3\nword4\nword5'
```

Comment: Take a close look at the expected output ;)

Comment: You replaced the spacing between `word2` and `word3` with a newline.